# Block reduction need someone to check my work

Tags: control-engineering, transfer-function, diagram

I tried to solve this block but I am not sure if the end result is any good, some feedback would be nice.
[image]

Comment: Do you want positive or negative feedback? Jokes aside, your working out looks correct.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is incorrect. Problem lies in going from step 2 to 3. (1-G5) term can be taken in denominator of G4 only if they are in feedback loop. In this case, they are not in loop and as a result, your answer is wrong.
The correct answer would be:

 Y=X[(G5+(G1/(1-G1*G3)*(1-G5)))*G2+G1*G4/(1-G1*G3)] 
Thank you